# How to iterate over results of query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

i am new to postgresql trying to itterate the select query. first i want use select query after getting the value want to iterate the result set and process this this record set and insert one by one into accounts table. but while executing this function postgresql give error
below is the error

```
ERROR:  record "setting_rows" has no field "id"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT 
            "Id", "AppValue", "UcValue", "AppRefId", "UcRefId",
            "integrationId", "DefaultUc", "SettingId", "DefaultApp",
            "Exclude", "AppFieldType", "UcFieldType"
                                                                                                                                                         FROM mappings 
        WHERE "SettingId" = setting_rows.Id
        LIMIT 1"
PL/pgSQL function "setWorkorderStatus"() line 25 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42703
```

any help will be appreciated, thanx in advance

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public."setWorkorderStatus"();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."setWorkorderStatus"()
    RETURNS VOID 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
    r_count INTEGER;
    setting_rows RECORD;
    s_id BIGINT;
    AppValue TEXT;
    UcValue TEXT ;
    AppRefId TEXT;
    UcRefId TEXT;
    integrationId BIGINT;
    DefaultUc BOOLEAN;
    SettingId BIGINT;
    DefaultApp BOOLEAN;
    Exclude BOOLEAN;
    AppFieldType TEXT;
    UcFieldType TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOR setting_rows IN SELECT "Id","integrationId", "Key", "Value", "VendorClientId", "Appkey", "UCkey" FROM settings WHERE "Key" = 'wo_order_statuses' LOOP
        SELECT 
            "Id", "AppValue", "UcValue", "AppRefId", "UcRefId",
            "integrationId", "DefaultUc", "SettingId", "DefaultApp",
            "Exclude", "AppFieldType", "UcFieldType"
        INTO
            s_id, AppValue, UcValue, AppRefId, UcRefId,
            integrationId, DefaultUc, SettingId, DefaultApp,
            Exclude, AppFieldType, UcFieldType
        FROM mappings 
        WHERE "SettingId" = setting_rows.Id
        LIMIT 1;
        INSERT INTO accounts(name,balance)
        VALUES(s_id,700);
    END LOOP;
END
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public."setWorkorderStatus"()
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: You have to fetch the results that can be found in your variable setting_rows, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING But you could also rewrite the code and use just a single query, instead of 3 queries and a loop.

Comment: The source of your error is you are using MixedCase  and you will need to quote the field name `"Id"` everywhere you reference it, including in the `record`. This means `setting_rows.Id` needs to be `setting_rows."Id"`. Make your life easier and stick with lower case identifiers. For why see [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).